# How to analyze traffic made by device on local Wifi network

Tags: wireshark

I have a device (Air quality sensor) that is sending data to a preconfigured server. I would like to access the data that is being sent.

Device connects to local Wifi (WPA Secured) and presumably every so often will send data.

I have tried using Wireshark for this, however, setting the adapter in "monitor" mode only allows me to see IEEE 802.11 layer, without actually being able to glimpse "into" anything meaningful. I would appreciated hints as to where to go from here.

Comment: The Wi-Fi frame payload is encrypted. You need to try to capture this on the ethernet side after it is decrypted. Something like configuring a mirror on a switch.

Comment: For 802.11 traffic, the 802.11 headers is all you really need to understand what is going on at the wireless level. If you are trying to analyze application traffic, then that would be encrypted. Even if you didn't have the wireless encryption the traffic is likely encrypted with TLS or by other means. What exactly are you trying to "analyze"?